# Samba unix permissions messed up despite mask

Tags: linux, permissions, samba, chmod, samba4

I'd like to configure a share on a standalone samba serve where users have `rw` to their own files, but `r` to others in the same group (`rwx` and `rx` on folders respectively). It works well when users creating new files and directories, but after certain file operations the file becomes `rwx` for group, which is undesirable.

The share is configured as this:

```
[share]
  path = /mnt/asd/bsd
  read only = yes
  valid users = @agroup, auser
  write list = @agroup
  directory mask = 0755
  create mask = 0644
  force group = +agroup
```

Reproduction, share is mounted as a drive on a Windows 8.1 client:

1. copy a x.jpg into the sare - so far so good, it becomes 644, owned by the user who created it and group is enforced as well
2. open the .jpg from the share with Windows Photo Viewer, rotate it - after the file gets saved upon closing it becomes mode 674 - too bad
3. right click > properties > security tab still shows only "read" permission for the group, there's no way to fix this remotely.

The same is happening when I right click the file in Windows and try to edit the permissions.

```
/ # smbd --version
Version 4.2.9
```

Is it a misconfig, or is there a way to restrict remote file mode changes? Tried to play with masks, or other config options so far no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, it looks like some ACL magic is happening in the background, so samba correctly sets the altered user / group / other unix mode to 7 in order to make sure ACLs are propagated.

So there's nothing to worry about, despite 0674 mode the file is not actually group writable, enforced via ACL.

ACL support could be disabled per share with `nt acl support = no`.